# Microcode on Time Processing Unit (TPU)

Tags: assembly, processor, microprocessors

I read about microcodes, and tried to understand what it means. But, I had a hard time understanding it. Can someone please clarify some of the confusion that I have?

Apparently, microcode is a built-in code, sitting on a ROM that performs hardware level instruction implementation of machine code at hardware circuitary level. Machine language operates at the hardware abstraction’s upper layer, but Microcode works at the low-level circuit-based operations.

But what does that mean? Does it mean that every CPU MUST have a Microcode embedded in it, on some sort of flash or ROM, or else the machine code will not be able to get translated in CPU?

But shouldn't Microcode be an application specific code? How can it be sitting there knowing what to do?
For example, let's say that one application moves the value of Register 1 (R1) into Register 2.
But I have a second application that takes R1 and mutiply it by 2, and then move it to R2.

So, does this mean that my two applications have two different Microcode?

Also, Freescale makes bunch of processors with something called eTPU (Time Processing Unit)

http://www.ashware.com/etpu-tpu.htm

But, I am really not sure what that means. It says that there are 64 total channels in eTPU. But, what is the definition of channel? Is it referring to a single I/O pin? The example they have in the above artcile is little confusing to me, can someone please give a more clear example of how we would take advantage of writing a custom Microcode using eTPU?

Thanks, 
--Rudy

Answer (score 2):

I'm an eTPU specialist, there aren't many of us. Microcoding the TPU used to be the normal means of development 15 years ago then it became the eTPU then realistically since the development of compilers like the Bytecraft and Ashware products the use of Microcode is in my experience a historic legacy.

The concept of Microcode is really that once upon a time even Assembly was considered to be a high level language. These days when you compare it to the likes of Python that's a lamentable situation, but historically it was thus. The Microcode is effectively the machine code, it's the untamed layer below of direct interface to the hardware. This presents itself in the usage scenario by such things as memory access, say I want to move data from location A to location B. Typically in assembly you would expect a long or short MOV to handle that. In microcode the game is not so clear as you may need to load paging registers, or push addresses into multiple registers as defined by the hardware, etc.  Now this does not mean it doesn't happen in Assembly, it does...  However, the assembly is considered to be an abstraction layer.

The eTPU does not have 64 channels, it has 32. You do get dual eTPU processors though which would have 64 channels in two cores. The base architecture of the processor allocates one channel per pin, this is the basic rule... However, via tools innovations and tricks of the trade you can access multiple pins from a given channel. The channels need to be thought of as independent control threads associated with a given pin, but...

The eTPU is a fantastic tool for the development of time critical response, triggering and tracking situations. It's ideal for following the position of a car engine; robotic control; multi-channel information requiring significant processing and rapid response. It's been used for motor control and such applications for years. It can be used for the old chestnuts of PSB control, data ports, etc. The fantastic asset it brings is that it's almost a second independent core, but has significant specialization.

In my opinion the eTPU is a much underutilized platform, another one you might look at that is easier to grasp the fundamentals of is the Texas CLA, as shipped on their C2000 processors. Same idea, not nearly as powerful but simpler and cheaper to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Microcode is, in fact, an hardware-assisted interpreter of machine code. It is used in some CPUs (including x86) and use of microcode usually means that the architecture is too complicated to implement in hardware. Roughly said, an Intel CPU doesn't executes x86 instructions directly, but rather runs a small program written for a a sightly simpler ISA, called microcode, which interprets x86 instructions. In the most architectures (including Intel/AMD) microcode is a top-secret burn-before-reading. The term microcode is also sometimes incorrectly used for any non-general purpose ISA.

About the channels... It can mean whatever... Try to find some docs.

Answer (score 0):

"Consider etpu as microcontroller insode a micorcontroller"
As eTPU/TPU is a RISC implementation so to control TPU processor we use 
microcode"The lowest-level instructions that directly control a microprocessor" 
ETPU has channels 32 in one ETPU engine so freescale controlers have two etpu engine.

Channel is mapped to  a pin
each pin can be configured as input pin/output pin
when input ,pin it can detect transitions(UART can be implements)
when output ,it can generate PWM and may other things

Now for making etpu do things one must instruct etpu engine.
etpu engine fetches instruction from shared memory
we using register write in that location to it work
now what etpu understands is microcode
How it works and written is a complex thing 
I am etpu novice  it will be good if you look at link bleow
you can refer following link
1.http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers-and-processors/power-architecture-processors/mpc5xxx-5xxx-32-bit-mcus/mpc56xx-mcus/enhanced-time-processor-unit:eTPU?